# Defining smallest possible sized macro in C

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, macros

I want to define a boolean macro in C that uses less than 4 bytes. I have looked into this, and maybe it is possible to define an asm macro, with gcc, that could be less. It is important that the definition will be small because I will have tens of thousands of matrices which hold these boolean values, and it is important that they can be as memory efficient as possible. Ideally, I want to define a 4-bit, or 8-bit macro that represents true and false, and will evaluate as such in an if-statement.

Edit:

When I define a macro

```
#define True 0
#define False !True
```

and then print the size, it returns a size of 4 bytes, which is very inefficient.

Edit2:

I just read up on bitpacking, and however little bits I could have for a boolean would be best. I'm just not too sure how to bitpack a struck that has the size of a few bits.

Edit3:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define false (unsigned char(0))
#define true (!false)

int main() {
    if (true) {
        printf("The size of true is %d\n", sizeof(true));
    }
}
```

gives the following output

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:8:9: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
test.c:9:51: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
```

Comment: How do you define the size of a macro?

Comment: Are you looking for `char` (or `int8_t`)?

Comment: You may be confused - a macro is not a variable or data type (it's something processed and expanded by the compiler / pre-processor.) The smallest representation of a boolean value is a bit, so what you probably want is a compressed data structure packing 8 booleans into one byte. Please edit your question if so, or explain why it has to be 4 or 8-bit specifically.

Comment: OT: Why the inverted logic?

Comment: int8 is fine, but I would rather have something smaller.

Comment: smaller is not more efficient.  bytes are pretty innefficient on modern processors 32 or 64 bit sized values (the size of the register) is the most efficient size.  x86 has 8 and 16 and 32 and 64 bit sized registers so from that angle a byte is not bad, then it goes to the bus transfer (if in ram) for efficiency and a single byte costs the same as something larger so no need to work to get that small..

Comment: The only reason to avoid using a 64-bit integer is because my program could use an upwards of 26 gigs of RAM.

Comment: @user1876508: 99% of the time, packing booleans into single bits will cost you more in code size than you save in data size. But if you need to store billions of them, it makes perfectly good sense to do so. It's a tradeoff.

Comment: Yes, I redid my macro a touch and tested it at codepad...

Comment: (Re)defining `true` and `false` is a dumb idea since C99 is out.

Comment: It's dumb to call people dumb when they need to have a more memory efficient representation of something.

Comment: If you are storing "tens of thousands" of booleans you should use a [bit array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525310/).

Comment: In Lenin's words, "the Truth doesn't matter; what matters is what people believe.". In that sense, `sizeof(true) == false` would be quite reasonable ;-) - trying to say, there's a difference between _data types_ for boolean, and _values_ that can be assigned to them. What you want is C++ `bitset`, which wraps `bool` _accessors_ over a compact bit array _representation_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead for your macros:

```
#define false ((unsigned char) 0)
#define true (!false)
```

This won't fix your space needs though.  For more efficient storage, you need to use bits:

```
void SetBoolValue(int bitOffset, unsigned char *array, bool value)
{
    int index = bitOffset >> 3;
    int mask = 1 << (bitOffset & 0x07);

    if (value)
        array[index] |= mask;
    else
        array[index] &= ~mask;
}

bool GetBoolValue(int bitOffset, unsigned char *array)
{
    int index = bitOffset >> 3;
    int mask = 1 << (bitOffset & 0x07);

    return array[index] & mask;
}
```

Where each value of "array" can hold 8 bools.  On modern systems, it can be faster to use a U32 or U64 as the array, but it can take up more space for smaller amounts of data.

To pack larger amounts of data:

```
void SetMultipleBoolValues(int bitOffset, unsigned char *array, int value, int numBitsInValue)
{
    for(int i=0; i<numBitsInValue; i++)
    {
        SetBoolValue(bitOffset + i, array, (value & (1 << i)));
    }
}
```

And here would be a driver:

```
int main(void)
{
    static char array[32];  // Static so it starts 0'd.
    int value = 1234;  // An 11-bit value to pack

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        SetMultipleBoolValues(i * 11, array, value, 11);  // 11 = 11-bits of data - do it 4 times

    for(int i=0; i<32; i++)
       printf("%c", array[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried this; but, it does not evaluate as true when I have an if statement if (True) { /* Do Something */}

Comment: Because my macro was backwards - lame on me.  Fixed.

Comment: Note, it should be `#define true (!false)`

Comment: My compiler is still not liking this, let me edit my original post to show you.

Comment: Those macros are not particularly useful -- and the first one is a syntax error (you got the cast syntax wrong). They specify *values* for `true` and `false`; any use of those values will be converted to some storage format, which you'll have to define anyway. Writing `#define true 1` and `#define false 0` is clearer and just as good -- and even that's unnecessary if you have `#include <stdbool.h>`.

Comment: As it's C here: Shouldn't it be `#define false ((unsigned char) 0)`?

Comment: Seat of my pants guys.  I'll fix the macro.  The bit vector was where I was going with this...

Comment: "*typedef would be cleaner*" - why? These aren't type definitions

Comment: Ok, redid it a bit and test compiled it over at codepad.  I know better than to blind code stuff anyways...

Comment: And eliminated that statement @icepack.  Trying to get the answer as clean as possible for y'all.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this in a structure, then you will want to use a bit field.

```
struct {
    unsigned flag : 1;
    /* other fields */
};
```

If you are wanting an array of boolean values, you should implement a bit vector (I was about to implement one, but Michael Dorgan's already done it).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there's no storage associated with your macros; they expand to the integer *constants* `0` and `1`.  The `sizeof` evaluates to 4 because the *expressions* have integer type.  You can certainly assign those values to objects of smaller type (`short` or `char`).

For me, life got a lot simpler when I *stopped* using `TRUE` and `FALSE` macros<sup>1</sup>.  Remember that in C, a zero-valued integral expression evaluates to false, and all non-zero-valued integral expressions evaluate to true.

If you want to store values into something smaller than 8 bits, then you're going to have to do your own bit packing, something like

```
#define TEST(x,bit) ((x) & (1 << (bit)))
#define SET(x,bit) ((x) |= (1 << (bit)))
#define CLEAR(x,bit) ((x) &= ~(1 << (bit)))
```

The smallest useful type for this is `unsigned char`.  So if you need to store N single-bit values, you need an array of N/CHAR_BIT+1 elements.  For example, to store 10 single-bit boolean values, you need 2 eight-bit array elements. Bits 0 through 7 will be stored in element 0, and bits 8 through 10 will be stored in element 1.

So, something like

```
#define MAX_BITS 24
unsigned char bits[MAX_BITS / CHAR_BIT + 1];

int bit = ...;

SET(bits[bit/CHAR_BIT], bit % CHAR_BIT);

if ( TEST(bits[bit/CHAR_BIT], bit % CHAR_BIT) )
{
  // do something if bit is set
}

CLEAR(bits[bit/CHAR_BIT], bit % CHAR_BIT);
```

No warranties express or implied; I don't do a lot of bit twiddling.  But hopefully this at least points you in the right direction.

---

<sup>1. The precipitating event was someone dropping a header where `TRUE` == `FALSE`.  Not the most productive afternoon.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just use an `unsigned char`, it will be the smallest individually addressable type:

```
typedef unsigned char smallBool;

smallBool boolMatrix[M][N];
```

The above will use `M * N` bytes for the matrix.

Of course, wasting `CHAR_BIT - 1` bits to store a single bit is ... wasteful. Consider bit-packing the boolean values.

Comment: How would they evaluate in an if statement? For example, let's say I want to look at the i-th row and j-th column and say

   if (boolMatrix[i][j]) { return 1}