# Efficient bitstream convolution

Tags: fft, convolution

I have two floating point time series A, B of length N each. I have to calculate the circular convolution and find maximum value. The classic and fastest way of doing this is

C = iFFT(FFT(A) * FFT(B))

Now, let's suppose that both A and B is a series which contains only 1s and 0s, so in principle we can represent them as bitstreams.

Question: Is there any faster way of doing the convolution (and find its maximum value) if I am somehow able to make use of the fact above ?

(I was already thinking a lot on Walsh - Hadamard transforms and SSE instructions, popcounts, but found no faster way for M > 2 **20 which is my case.)

Thanks,
gd

Comment: Is it just the maximum value you are interested in, or do you need the whole convolution to be computed as well? (Note I haven't started thinking through a solution yet, so don't get excited that I'll have a useful trick based on that.) You're basically looking for the maximum of the total number of bits in A&B for all bitwise rotations of A, right?

Comment: Question belongs in the dsp stack exchange

Comment: Also, is there anything special about the distribution of either series? Is one sparse? Are they similar and you're trying to estimate delay? Are they PWM representations of sinusoidal signals? Do you have a window that you expect the maximum to fall in?

Comment: Thanks for the question, I need 'only' the maximum value and its position. I wrote 0s and 1s but those are representing 1s and -1s in fact. So the problem cannot be translated into the one you wrote, but I need the maximum number of bits in not(xor(a,b)) for all bitwise rotation. A series is a 'white noise' B series is some pattern.

Comment: You may be able to use a multi-scale search, although it may not always converge on the absolute maximum. Downsample the two signals by a factor such as 16 and find the maximum cross-correlation. Then re-run the search at the original sample rate, searching only offsets within 16 samples of the maximum found in the previous step. Obviously this can be done in several passes at different rates (which is why i picked a power of two), and FFT-based techniques are still applicable. However, this doesn't gain anything from the 0/1 representation, so there may be a better method.

Comment: Thanks Katie, this is a good idea, and I was also considering, however the problem here is that the maximum frequency of the template (pattern, B series) is close to the sampling rate's Nyquist frequency, as a result any downsampling would cause information loss of information and results in biased maximum....this downsampling technique works fine only if the sampling rate is much higher than the pattern 'frequency'.

Comment: Yeah, it's a technique used in 2-dimensional pattern matching for image processing, where the low frequency components tend to work well for a good approximation. Since your A series is white noise I suppose filtering anything out will kill enough of B that it may converge in a much different spot. I doubt you'll find much better than the FFT technique then. Maybe consider a fixed-point integer approach - i think a 32 bit int should be more than accurate enough if you're on the order of 2**20 samples.

Answer (score 1):

The 1D convolution `c` of two arrays `a` and `b` of size `n` is an array such that :

[image: formula]

This formula can be rewritten in an iterative way :

[image: formula2]

The non-null terms of the sum are limited to the number of changes `nb` of `b` : if `b` is a simple pattern, this sum can be limited to a few terms. An algorithm may now be designed to compute `c` :

1 : compute `c[0]`   (about `n` operations)

2 : for `0<i<n` compute `c[i]` using the formula (about `nb*n` operations)

If `nb` is small, this method may be faster than fft. Note that it will provide exact results for bitstream signals, while the fft needs oversampling and floating point precision to deliver accurate results.

Here is a piece of code implementing this trick with input type `unsigned char`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <fftw3.h>

typedef struct{
    unsigned int nbchange;
    unsigned int index[1000];
    int change[1000];
}pattern;

void topattern(unsigned int n, unsigned char* b,pattern* bp){
    //initialisation
    bp->nbchange=0;
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned char former=b[n-1];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(b[i]!=former){
            bp->index[bp->nbchange]=i;
            bp->change[bp->nbchange]=((int)b[i])-former;
            bp->nbchange++;
        }
        former=b[i];
    }
}

void printpattern(pattern* bp){
    int i;
    printf("pattern :\n");
    for(i=0;i<bp->nbchange;i++){
        printf("index %d change %d\n",bp->index[i],bp->change[i]);
    } 
}

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer

unsigned int NumberOfSetBits(unsigned int i)
{
    i = i - ((i >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    i = (i & 0x33333333) + ((i >> 2) & 0x33333333);
    return (((i + (i >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F) * 0x01010101) >> 24;
}

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525310/how-to-define-and-work-with-an-array-of-bits-in-c

unsigned int convol_longint(unsigned int a, unsigned int b){
    return NumberOfSetBits(a&b);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    unsigned int n=10000000;

    //the array a
    unsigned char* a=malloc(n*sizeof(unsigned char));
    if(a==NULL){printf("malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    unsigned int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        a[i]=rand();
    }
    memset(&a[2],5,2);
    memset(&a[10002],255,20);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        //printf("a %d %d \n",i,a[i]);
    }

    //pattern b
    unsigned char* b=malloc(n*sizeof(unsigned char));
    if(b==NULL){printf("malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    memset(b,0,n*sizeof(unsigned char));
    memset(&b[2],1,20);


    //memset(&b[120],1,10);
    //memset(&b[200],1,10);

    int* c=malloc(n*sizeof(int)); //nb bit in the array
    memset(c,0,n*sizeof(int));

    clock_t begin, end;
    double time_spent;

    begin = clock();
    /* here, do your time-consuming job */


    //computing c[0]
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        //c[0]+= convol_longint(a[i],b[i]);
        c[0]+= ((int)a[i])*((int)b[i]);
        //printf("c[0] %d %d\n",c[0],i);
    }
    printf("c[0] %d\n",c[0]);

    //need to store b as a pattern.
    pattern bpat;
    topattern( n,b,&bpat);
    printpattern(&bpat);

    //computing c[i] according to formula
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        c[i]=c[i-1];
        for(j=0;j<bpat.nbchange;j++){
            c[i]+=bpat.change[j]*((int)a[(bpat.index[j]-i+n)%n]);
        }
    }

    //finding max
    int currmax=c[0];
    unsigned int currindex=0;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        if(c[i]>currmax){
            currmax=c[i];
            currindex=i;
        }
        //printf("c[i] %d %d\n",i,c[i]);
    }

    printf("c[max] is %d at index %d\n",currmax,currindex);

    end = clock();
    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("computation took %lf seconds\n",time_spent);


    double* dp = malloc(sizeof (double) * n);
    fftw_complex * cp = fftw_malloc(sizeof (fftw_complex) * (n/2+1));

    begin = clock();
    fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(n, dp, cp, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    end = clock();
    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    fftw_execute ( plan );
    printf("fftw took %lf seconds\n",time_spent);

    free(dp);
    free(cp);

    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(c);
    return 0;
}
```

To compile : `gcc main.c -o main -lfftw3 -lm`

For `n=10 000 000` and `nb=2` (`b` is just a "rectangular 1D window") this algorithm run in 0.65 seconds on my computer. A double-precision fft using fftw took approximately the same time. This comparison, like most of comparisons, may be unfair since :

- `nb=2` is the best case for the algorithm presented in this answer.
- The fft-based algorithm would have needed oversampling.
- double precison may not be required for the fft-based algorithm
- The implementation exposed here is not optimized. It is just basic code.

This implementation can handle `n=100 000 000`. At this point, using long int for `c` could be advised to avoid any risk of overflow.

If signals are bitstreams, this program may be optimzed in various ways. For bitwise operations, look [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525310/how-to-define-and-work-with-an-array-of-bits-in-c) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is a good idea! Now I have to check how many "sign changes" is typically in my B series, however I'm afraid it will be more than log(4N), (factor 4 for the padding for FFT), so the total compute cost still will be more than 4N * log(4N).... I'll put this together and let you now. Thanks again !